# avr eclipse plugin not showing at eclipse ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I was using avr eclipse plugin in my ubuntu 12.04 with eclipse-cdt, now i upgraded to 14.04 and avr-eclipse plugin does not shows up after installation.

I found in 14.04 eclipse was not installed in /opt as 12.04

How can i get avr-eclipse plugin work with ubuntu 14.04

I am using 64 bit machine

Comment: When you say you upgraded, did you use `sudo do-release-upgrade`, or did you reinstall?

Comment: i made a clean install of 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With eclipse, in general, you just throw the plugin you want into the plugins folder. Alternatively you can install it via Eclipse's software center.

It is worth noting that some plugins aren't compatible with some versions of eclipse - are you using the same version that you were using before? It appears that Eclipse 3.8 is the default version in the repositories for ubuntu (via `apt-get`). If you're looking for Indigo, Juno, Kepler or Luna, you can find downloads for them [on this page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: previously i was using indigo. is there any option so that i dont want to download a new eclipse and work with the 3.8

Comment: re-read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: i will install indigo again